# Simple Google ReCaptcha validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, captcha

**Linked:**
[Google reCAPTCHA Validator: Iteration II](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100604/google-recaptcha-validator-iteration-ii)

---

I have also created a simple Google Recaptcha Validation class to handle verification.

I used some code from CodingFusion's post [Google New reCaptcha I am not a robot using asp .net](http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Google-New-reCaptcha-I-am-not-a-robot-using-asp-n), but I have altered it so that it fit my use case, and to make it extendable and reusable.

Can I clean it up further?

```
public class ReCaptchaValidator
{
    private readonly string _ReCaptchaSecret;
    private readonly string _ReCaptchaSiteKey;
    public List<string> ErrorCodes { get; set; }

    public ReCaptchaValidator(string reCaptchaSecret)
    {
        _ReCaptchaSecret = reCaptchaSecret;
        this.ErrorCodes = new List<string>();
    }
    public ReCaptchaValidator(string reCaptchaSecret, string reCaptchaSiteKey)
    {
        _ReCaptchaSecret = reCaptchaSecret;
        _ReCaptchaSiteKey = reCaptchaSiteKey;
        this.ErrorCodes = new List<string>();
    }

    public bool ValidateCaptcha(HttpRequest request)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=");
        sb.Append(_ReCaptchaSecret);
        sb.Append("&response=");
        sb.Append(request.Form["g-recaptcha-response"]);

        //client ip address
        sb.Append("&remoteip=");
        sb.Append(GetUserIp(request));

        //make the api call and determine validity
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var uri = sb.ToString();
            var json = client.DownloadString(uri);
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RecaptchaApiResponse));
            var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
            var result = serializer.ReadObject(ms) as RecaptchaApiResponse;

            if (result == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if (result.ErrorCodes != null)
            {
                foreach(var code in result.ErrorCodes)
                {                        
                    this.ErrorCodes.Add(code.ToString());
                }
                return false;
            }
            else if (!result.Success)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else //-- If successfully verified.
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    //--- To get user IP(Optional)
    private string GetUserIp(HttpRequest request)
    {
        var visitorsIpAddr = string.Empty;

        if (request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null)
        {
            visitorsIpAddr = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.UserHostAddress))
        {
            visitorsIpAddr = request.UserHostAddress;
        }
        return visitorsIpAddr;
    }

}
[DataContract]
public class RecaptchaApiResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "success")]
    public bool Success;

    [DataMember(Name = "error-codes")]
    public List<string> ErrorCodes;
}
```

Comment: I never thought to use `DataContract`s for mine, that's a good write!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
private readonly string _ReCaptchaSecret;
private readonly string _ReCaptchaSiteKey;
```

`private` fields are either `lowerCamelCase` or `_lowerCamelCase`, both conventions are common.

---

```
public ReCaptchaValidator(string reCaptchaSecret)
{
    _ReCaptchaSecret = reCaptchaSecret;
    this.ErrorCodes = new List<string>();
}
public ReCaptchaValidator(string reCaptchaSecret, string reCaptchaSiteKey)
{
    _ReCaptchaSecret = reCaptchaSecret;
    _ReCaptchaSiteKey = reCaptchaSiteKey;
    this.ErrorCodes = new List<string>();
}
```

Don't repeat work in your constructors: use chaining instead.

```
public ReCaptchaValidator(string reCaptchaSecret)
{
    _ReCaptchaSecret = reCaptchaSecret;
    this.ErrorCodes = new List<string>();
}

public ReCaptchaValidator(string reCaptchaSecret, string reCaptchaSiteKey) 
    : this (reCaptchaSecret)
{
    _ReCaptchaSiteKey = reCaptchaSiteKey;
}
```

---

With C# 6, you can also use a property initializer to.. initialize.. your property.

```
public List<string> ErrorCodes { get; set; }

public ReCaptchaValidator(string reCaptchaSecret)
{
    _ReCaptchaSecret = reCaptchaSecret;
    this.ErrorCodes = new List<string>();
}
```

becomes

```
public List<string> ErrorCodes { get; set; } = new List<string>();

public ReCaptchaValidator(string reCaptchaSecret)
{
    _ReCaptchaSecret = reCaptchaSecret;
}
```

---

I would also advise to use a `private` setter for your `ErrorCodes` like this:

```
public List<string> ErrorCodes { get; private set; } = new List<string>();
```

Likewise, with C# 6, you might as well make it a readonly property:

```
public List<string> ErrorCodes { get; } = new List<string>();
```

---

StringBuilders see their most use when you're concatenating strings in a loop. In this scenario I would use a formatted string which turns this:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=");
sb.Append(_ReCaptchaSecret);
sb.Append("&response=");
sb.Append(request.Form["g-recaptcha-response"]);
sb.Append("&remoteip=");
sb.Append(GetUserIp(request));
```

into this:

```
var uri = string.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}&remoteip={2}",
    _ReCaptchaSecret, 
    request.Form["g-recaptcha-response"], 
    GetUserIp(request));
```

Or with C# 6:

```
var uri = $"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={_ReCaptchaSecret}&response={(request.Form["g-recaptcha-response"])}&remoteip={GetUserIp(request)}";
```

---

```
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.UserHostAddress))
```

I prefer `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` because only rarely whitespace characters are considered good input.

Comment: I could not remember the chaining like this for some reason. I just read about it too!  thank you!

Comment: I was able to do this `private readonly List<string> _errorCodes = new List<string>();` does that mean that I am running C# 6?

Comment: No, not necessarily. That's a field, not a property. Fields can be instantiated inline, properties only can since C# 6.

Comment: you need to escape your quotes in the interpolated string

Comment: it appears that you need to have that expression inside of parenthesis.  like so --> `{(request.Form["g-recaptcha-response"])}` via this [Stack Overflow Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33001597/1214743)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not a fan of properties in the form of:

```
public List<string> ErrorCodes { get; set; }
```

as someone can do this:

```
var validator = new ReCaptchaValidator("secretstuff");

validator.ErrorCodes = new List<string> { "Bogus error!" };
```

or some such. I might code it as such:

```
private readonly IList<string> _ErrorCodes = new List<string>();

public ReCaptchaValidator(string reCaptchaSecret) : this(reCaptchaSecret, null)
{
}

public ReCaptchaValidator(string reCaptchaSecret, string reCaptchaSiteKey)
{
    _ReCaptchaSecret = reCaptchaSecret;
    _ReCaptchaSiteKey = reCaptchaSiteKey;
}

public IEnumerable<string> ErrorCodes
{
    get
    {
        return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(this._ErrorCodes);
    }
}
```

Then replace all your use of `ErrorCodes` with `_ErrorCodes` within the class.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
>         if (result == null)
>         {
>             return false;
>         }
>         else if (result.ErrorCodes != null)
>         {
>             foreach(var code in result.ErrorCodes)
>             {                        
>                 this.ErrorCodes.Add(code.ToString());
>             }
>             return false;
>         }
>         else if (!result.Success)
>         {
>             return false;
>         }
>         else //-- If successfully verified.
>         {
>             return true;
>         }
> ```

Well this is ugly.

First the `else` is redundant, because for each of the other conditions you are returning a value hence the `else` will be reached only if the previous conditions aren't met.

The last `else if` is superfluous too, because you have something like this:

```
if(condition)
{
    return true;
}
else
{ 
    return true;
}
```

which should be compacted to `return condition;`.

This will lead to:

```
        if (result == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (result.ErrorCodes != null)
        {
            foreach(var code in result.ErrorCodes)
            {                        
                this.ErrorCodes.Add(code.ToString());
            }
            return false;
        }

        return result.Success;
```

But hey, we can do one better.

- because `result.ErrorCodes` is a `List<string>` there is no need to call `ToString()` on any item of this list.
- because `this.ErrorCodes` is a `List<string>` too, we can take advantage of the `AddRange()` method.

This will lead to:

```
        if (result == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (result.ErrorCodes != null)
        {
            this.ErrorCodes.AddRange(result.ErrorCodes);
            return false;
        }

        return result.Success;
```