# Google reCAPTCHA Validator: Iteration III

Tags: c#, object-oriented, .net, captcha

This is the third iteration of my reCAPTCHA validator. Iteration II can be found at: [Google reCAPTCHA Validator: Iteration II](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100604/google-recaptcha-validator-iteration-ii)

It does *almost everything* required to do reCAPTCHA validation on anything .NET.

I removed all the XML docs to shorten it up a bit.

GitHub commit of the version in this thread (with all the docs added that I omitted here): [ReCaptchaValidator.cs](https://github.com/EBrown8534/Framework/blob/58f661b3b62640e3dc5aa706f8c0d0174be53e62/Evbpc.Framework/Integrations/Google/ReCaptchaValidator.cs)

The only comments I do not wish to hear of are any comments relating to my use of fully-qualifying static/const members. I do this primarily to remind myself of where they originate.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace Evbpc.Framework.Integrations.Google
{
    public class ReCaptchaValidator
    {
        private const string _headScriptInclude = "<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>";
        private const string _bodyDivInclude = "<div class=\"g-recaptcha %EXTRACLASSES%\" data-sitekey=\"%SITEKEY%\"></div>";
        private const string _reCaptchaFormCode = "g-recaptcha-response";
        private const string _googleApiEndpoint = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";

        private readonly string _reCaptchaSecret;
        private readonly string _reCaptchaSiteKey;
        private readonly List<string> _extraClasses = new List<string>();

        public string HeadScriptInclude => ReCaptchaValidator._headScriptInclude;
        public List<string> ExtraClasses => _extraClasses;
        public string BodyDivInclude => GetBodyDivContent(this.ExtraClasses);

        public ReCaptchaValidator(string reCaptchaSecret, string reCaptchaSiteKey)
        {
            _reCaptchaSecret = reCaptchaSecret;
            _reCaptchaSiteKey = reCaptchaSiteKey;
        }

        public ReCaptchaResponse Validate(NameValueCollection form, string remoteIp = null)
        {
            string reCaptchaSecret = _reCaptchaSecret;
            string reCaptchaResponse = form[ReCaptchaValidator._reCaptchaFormCode];

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                NameValueCollection postParameters = new NameValueCollection() { { "secret", reCaptchaSecret }, { "response", reCaptchaResponse } };

                if (remoteIp != null)
                {
                    postParameters.Add("remoteip", remoteIp);
                }

                byte[] response = client.UploadValues(ReCaptchaValidator._googleApiEndpoint, postParameters);

                string reCaptchaResult = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);

                ReCaptchaResponse result = new ReCaptchaResponse();

                if (result.ParseJson(reCaptchaResult))
                {
                    return result;
                }

                return null;
            }
        }

        public string GetBodyDivContent(List<string> extraClasses)
        {
            string result = ReCaptchaValidator._bodyDivInclude;

            result = result.Replace("%SITEKEY%", _reCaptchaSiteKey);

            if (extraClasses != null)
            {
                result = result.Replace("%EXTRACLASSES%", string.Join(" ", extraClasses));
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    public class ReCaptchaResponse
    {
        private bool _success = false;
        private ReCaptchaErrors _errors = ReCaptchaErrors.None;

        public bool Success => _success; 
        public ReCaptchaErrors Errors => _errors;

        public bool ParseJson(string jsonResponse)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            dynamic deserializedJson = jss.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse);

            if (deserializedJson.ContainsKey("success"))
            {
                _success = deserializedJson["success"];
                _errors = ReCaptchaErrors.None;

                if (deserializedJson.ContainsKey("error-codes"))
                {
                    foreach (string error in deserializedJson["error-codes"])
                    {
                        // Our `ReCaptchaErrors` enum contains the exact same strings as the returned `error` text would be, with the following transformations:
                        // 1. The words are transformed to PascalCase;
                        // 2. The dashes are stripped;
                        string[] errorWords = error.Split('-');

                        string errorEnumName = "";
                        foreach (string errorWord in errorWords)
                        {
                            errorEnumName += errorWord[0].ToString().ToUpper() + errorWord.Substring(1);
                        }

                        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ReCaptchaErrors), errorEnumName))
                        {
                            _errors = _errors | (ReCaptchaErrors)Enum.Parse(typeof(ReCaptchaErrors), errorEnumName);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum ReCaptchaErrors
    {
        None = 0x00,
        MissingInputSecret = 1 << 0,
        InvalidInputSecret = 1 << 1,
        MissingInputResponse = 1 << 2,
        InvalidInputResponse = 1 << 3,
    }
}
```

Yes, this is the first question I have asked here with *all* the braces included.

This is part of an [open-source library](https://github.com/EBrown8534/Framework/tree/master) I have which, as usual, anyone is free to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The strings `"success"` and `"error-codes"` should be `const string`.

---

Why is the construction of `postParameters` inside `using (WebClient client = new WebClient())`? On that same topic: considering `client` isn't used after it has filled `response`, why keep it open? Basically, only `response = client.UploadValues(ReCaptchaValidator._googleApiEndpoint, postParameters);` should be inside `using (WebClient client = new WebClient())` (with `byte[] response` defined outside of it).

You also don't need the empty argument at the end of `NameValueCollection()`.

---

Can `remoteIp` be an empty string? Otherwise, why not use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` instead of `if (remoteIp != null)`?

---

There's no need to do this:

```
string result = ReCaptchaValidator._bodyDivInclude;
result = result.Replace("%SITEKEY%", _reCaptchaSiteKey);
```

Just do it in one line:

```
string result = ReCaptchaValidator._bodyDivInclude.Replace("%SITEKEY%", _reCaptchaSiteKey);
```

---

I'm not a fan of an enum with a plural as a name: `ReCaptchaErrors`. Especially since you then named the field `_errors`, which suggests a collection. Same for `Errors`.

---

Why do you [use `JavaScriptSerializer` and not Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18314625/648075)?

---

You can reduce the indentation by re-thinkign your if-else blocks:

```
if (!deserializedJson.ContainsKey("success"))
{
    return false;
}

_success = deserializedJson["success"];
_errors = ReCaptchaErrors.None;

if (!deserializedJson.ContainsKey("error-codes"))
{
    return true;
}
```

---

It's customary to use `string.Empty` instead of `""`: `string errorEnumName = "";`.

---

Move `errorWord[0].ToString().ToUpper() + errorWord.Substring(1);` to a method called `Capitalize` and rewrite it slightly:

```
private string Capitalize(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    return char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);
}
```

That way your `for` loop can become:

```
string errorEnumName = errorWords.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, errorWord) => current + Capitalize(errorWord));
```

---

I would consider converting `deserializedJson` to [a case insensitive `Dictionary<K, V>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8350258/648075) to avoid the `foreach`. Also, that way you can use `TryGetValue`.

Comment: I ended up renaming `Capitalize` to `ToPascalCase`, made it an extension method, and put it in a different class. :)

Comment: Re: the plural enum name - the [Enumeration Type Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x252001(v=vs.71).aspx) suggest this is correct, since it is a flags enum.

Answer (score 3):

Just one quick comment:

```
ReCaptchaResponse result = new ReCaptchaResponse();

if (result.ParseJson(reCaptchaResult))
{
    return result;
}
return null;
```

This would work better as static method following the familiar TryParse pattern:

```
ReCaptchaResponse result;
if (ReCaptchaResponse.TryParseJson(reCaptchaResult, out result))
{
    return result;
}
return null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Some changes I made (after noticing a few issues with it):

- `ExtraClasses` has no need to be a field *and* a property; replaced both with `public List<string> ExtraClasses { get; } = new List<string>();`.
- Since `GetBodyDivContent` is not `static`, I made removed `extraClasses` from the parameter, and made it directly used in the method.
- I extracted a lot of `Validate` out to other `protected` methods.
- I replaced `ParseJson` with `TryParseJson` as per [RobH's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/22816/robh) [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/105919/73844).

Version as of this answer: [ReCaptchaValidator.cs](https://github.com/EBrown8534/Framework/commit/81d8e07319c2248cb22cd2b3f048a5e50eb14ac1)

Comment: That looks a lot nicer, yes. Invalidates plenty of my review, though. ;-)

Comment: @BCdotWEB Although I am making substantial changes as a result of your review still. :)